# select only first letters of words from a varchar field

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I was asked in an interview,a question from oracle sql.this seemed to be a simple question but  i had no clue to answer.could anybody help?

if there is string like "newyork is a beautiful city" in a colum.

```
select column_name from table_name;
```

will result

```
newyork is a beautiful city
```

what is the query required to give the output as a string with all the first letters.
i.e., the output should be

```
niabc
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity: Is there a reason "a" was excluded from the output (i.e. why isn't it "niabc"?), or was part of the interview question to also remove articles?

Comment: If you really did need to do this, SQL is entirely the wrong tool for it. While you could write some monolithic recursive query, you could achieve the same thing (probably much faster too) with a simple loop in another language that you could plonk in a user defined function.

Comment: sorry ,my mistake...i forgot the a:)

Comment: @lins...you may be right...but maybe the interviewer was testing my logical skills and is not thinking about the performance that you are talking about.and i also agree this can be done easily with other tools available.

Comment: @lins, i disagree, if the SQL engine has the builtin capability to do this task, it is always cheaper in resources to let him do it.

Comment: @Am: Agreed. My point was that this is not something best done via set based logic. @benjamin button: This seems to be a matter of memorising functions that come with the database. If you didn't already know the function, the SQL way to do it would be via a recursive query, in which case I would mention that there are better alternatives first, then jump into SQL only if the interviewer insists, since it takes me a good half hour to write up a recursive query even when I've got a database to test on.

Comment: @lins...the interviewer specifically asked for an sql query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provided you're not concerned with maintaining the case of the output this can be done quite simply without the need for recursion:

```
SQL> select
  2      translate(
  3            initcap('newyork is a BEAUTIFUL city')
  4               , 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  5               , 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  6              )
  7  from dual
  8  /

TRANS
-----
NIABC

SQL>
```

If the sentence contains numerals, punctuation, etc then we would have to add those characters to the first replacement string, which could get rather tedious.

Comment: this is really excellent answer and this is what i was serching for ...a simple sql query:)thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is using **REGEX_SUBSTR**.

See the docs [here](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm),
and a close example [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/code/tips2007/070907.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the split function described [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3594201&) (replacing the comma by a space), in order to split the sentence by its spaces. Then, you could use the substr function as AJ says, because the result of the split would allow you to start from char 1 to char 2 of every "piece".

It involves substr after all, right??

PS. I would rather process the result in a layer above, not during the query. But that's me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would involve using the function [substr](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm)?

Comment: Any reason this is not valid?

Comment: substr will be used only if you know the position of the character u need. but you donot know where the word is exactly present. and added to this...this should not be an answer ,rater it should be a comment.so -1 from me

Comment: You got my upvote, @AJ :-) I've never used Oracle, but from a quick search it seems like either `substr` or `regex_substr` would work and either one is just as valid as the other, and those seem to be the only real choices for solving the problem. Maybe an Oracle guru will prove us all wrong by telling us about the `get_first_letter_of_every_word_please` function ;-)

Comment: @Mike, thanks and actually that's a valid answer:  define your own function in Oracle.

Comment: @AJ,and @Mike...this is not at all a valid answer....as you can see the accepted answer.