# Is there any possibility of using "? =" and "?<=" qualifiers inside the regular expressions in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Is there any possibility of using `?=` and `?<=` qualifiers inside the regular expressions in oracle sql?

Comment: Oracle doesn't support lookups afaik

Comment: Just match more, and capture only the part you need to use.

Comment: Please include your actual problem.  Maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: I need to get all words' first letters in text sentencies(in context of a SQL  request, of course). E.g. for string "Yersh Alex" i want to get "YA".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TRANSLATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174656/select-only-first-letters-of-words-from-a-varchar-field), but in my opinion is not easy to maintain. You also can use [regexp_replace](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/190030/) function. Basically, you are replacing everyting but the first letter of each word.

```
-- Solution 1
WITH T AS (
            SELECT 'Fredy Mercury' str FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Hello World' FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Abc Def Ghi Klm Opq' FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'As far as I know' FROM dual
            )  
SELECT str,
        TRANSLATE(INITCAP(str)
                    ,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                    ,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    FROM T;

-- Solution 2     
WITH T AS (
        SELECT 'Fredy Mercury' str FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Hello World' FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Abc Def Ghi Klm Opq' FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 'As far as I know' FROM dual
        )  
SELECT str, UPPER(regexp_replace(str,'(\w{1})\w*(\W+|$)','\1')) FROM T;
```

Hopefully, this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. This is a fully working solution